# MongoDb filtering on reference fields

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I am at a loss.  I am trying to add a filter on a MongoDB collection, but the field does not exist, only a reference to it does.

This is a field that I have in my mongoose schema:

```
  @Prop({ type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId, refPath: 'ClientEntity', required: true })
  clientRef: Types.ObjectId;
```

When I do a find, I want to do the following:

```
const query = { $or: [{ 'user.firstName': 'test }, { 'user.lastName': 'test' }] }

collection.countDocuments(query);
collection.find(query).limit(25).skip(0);
```

The problem is that `user` does not exists in my collection, only a reference to it. So the query is kind of ignored.

This causes me major headaches when wanting to do pagination for instance.  My current approach is to fetch documents (based on limit), populate the required properties and then filter out the documents that I want or need based on my requirements (like the query above).

This also poses a couple of problems.  If I fetch 25 documents, and filter out 20, I am left with 5.  I also cannot get an accurate count of all documents still available for the required query.

**I am not sure how to solve this issue or which approach is best.**

I have found solutions like to fetch more documents than I need.  For example, if I want 25 documents, fetch 50 or 100 and then just filter out.  I have also come across a solution to use MongoDB's `$lookup` stage in an aggregation pipeline.  But I am concerned this will cause performance issues on large collections.  I don't know which approach to take or where to go from here.

Any help, guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you're limiting the result, it causes to miss out on many documents, even with populating, and it won't be good to get all the documents, populate them, and then filter them out to limit the results. Have you considered querying `ClientEntity` and then add the documents from the desired collection, based on the ref `ObjectID`? That'll be ideal in this case if you can't have embedded documents and query without references.